# How to implement the In-App purchase process in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, in-app-purchase, in-app

I use Xamarin Forms and the Plugin.InAppBilling plugin. 
Do I have to run the restore the purchases method (LoadItemsAsync()) when the app starts at the first time or just when they press the 'Restore purchases' button?

And also when they try to buy the product how can I check if they ever bought it before?

Comment: James has docs that cover all that: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/

Comment: The doc hasn' got info about that I'm afraid. But thanks

Comment: Anyone knows this? Thanks